# Android studio - Error: AndroidManifest.xml doesn't exist or has incorrect root tag

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest

I was about to rebuild and run my app, when a window was opened and below it says `Error: AndroidManifest.xml doesn't exist or has incorrect root tag` so I opened my Manifest file to check what is exactly wrong and I found it like this:

```
/* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.
 *
 * This class was automatically generated by the
 * gradle plugin from the resource data it found. It
 * should not be modified by hand.
 */
package android.support.graphics.drawable.animated;

public final class R {
  private R() {}

public static final class attr {
    private attr() {}

    public static final int coordinatorLayoutStyle = 0x7f020070;
    public static final int font = 0x7f020089;
    public static final int fontProviderAuthority = 0x7f02008b;
    public static final int fontProviderCerts = 0x7f02008c;
    public static final int fontProviderFetchStrategy = 0x7f02008d;
    public static final int fontProviderFetchTimeout = 0x7f02008e;
    public static final int fontProviderPac`
```

I do not know from where did all of that came from I just realed a successful test a few minutes before trying again.
Now before you rush into marking this as a duplicate question, I have spent a lot of time looking into suggested solutions with no luck

**Update** I tried several solutions like resyncing, cleaning project, rebuilding but none of them worked

Comment: Have you tried to right-click `AndroidMainfest.xml` in your file explorer > `Local History` > `Show History`?

Comment: Yes I did do that, but unfortunately id didn't work